# Diagnosing Issue in Bench Power Supply with Buggy Display

Tags: power-supply, repair, display, troubleshooting

I have a BK Precision 1660 Power Supply with a buggy display. The system has two displays (master and slave), the slave display working perfectly fine while the master display will sometimes flash random values (usually negative). This problem is intermittent, usually working after being first powered up for an indeterminate amount of time before it devolves into buggy behavior. The output stays consistent during this however and I am still able to adjust voltage and everything I just cannot know the output without having a multimeter hooked up to it. I have tried several attempts to solve the issue to no avail. I have tested all the resistor values, I have replaced the central display driver 7107CPL, replaced unreliable slide switches (not pictured in schematic). Wondering if there are any other troubleshooting tips I could get from here.[image: Source: https://manuals.repeater-builder.com/te-files/BK%20PRECISION/BK%20PRECISION%201660%20Instruction.pdf]
Instruction Manual: https://manuals.repeater-builder.com/te-files/BK%20PRECISION/BK%20PRECISION%201660%20Instruction.pdf

EDIT:
took unit apart to try to test reference voltages when buggy behavior was occurring but seems the problem magically fixed itself. The metal exterior does slightly deform the boards when screwed in tight so I am just going to minimize the number of screws and try to stress the internals as little as possible. Unsatisfying answer but going to go ahead and mark as solved.

Comment: Could also be the circuit that sends data. By the way, could you add the source for the picture, either link or the name of user or service manual?

Comment: @MiNiMe [Instruction Manual](https://manuals.repeater-builder.com/te-files/BK%20PRECISION/BK%20PRECISION%201660%20Instruction.pdf)

Comment: if it works at first, that sounds like something is overheating. see if pointing a box fan on it helps; not that that's a fix, but it will help determine if it's really a heat issue.

Comment: you can also just plop a digital volt/ammeter onto the front, might not look great but working is better than not.

Answer (score 1):

You could check that you have a stable voltage reference on pins 35 & 36 of the A/D converter, by monitoring it with your multimeter.

You could also disconnect the DM- and DM1 connections and apply a stable voltage (small battery) on there to see if the display then stays stable. If it is stable, then the issue isn't with the display board.